# Can I make SSH Authentication Lightning Fast?

Tags: macos, authentication, ssh

I use SSH in a terminal window many times during a day.

I remember reading about a way to reuse a single connection so that the TCP and SSH handshaking don't have to happen every time I establish another request to the same host.

Can someone point me to a link or describe how to establish a shared ssh connection so that subsequent connections to the same host will connect quickly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question. [Improving SSH (OpenSSH) connection speed with shared connections](http://protempore.net/~calvins/howto/ssh-connection-sharing/) describes using the "ControlPath" configuration setting.

UPDATE: For connections that are opened and closed often add a setting like `ControlPersist 4h` to your ~/.ssh/config.  See [this post about SSH productivity tips](http://blogs.perl.org/users/smylers/2011/08/ssh-productivity-tips.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the terminal opened, the easiest way is producing I/O ("tail -f" or "while [ -d . ]; cat /etc/loadavg; sleep 3; done").

If you want to improve the connection handshake one way I use is adding "UseDNS no" on your sshd_config.

Comment: Oh, and remove unused authentications (gssapi-with-mic is very slow). You can also check what is your bootlenech with "ssh -v"

Comment: To deal with (frustrating yet frequent) ssh disconnects due to forced timeouts, inactivity, etc: after login (`ssh {hostname}`), immediately run a `screen` session (ie, `screen -S working-on-XYZ bash -l`). Also, I set my remote `~/.screenrc` to include something like: `caption always '%3n %H: %t // %c:%s'`, which may force the ssh session to 'keep alive' (due to the ticking clock running remotely, displaying locally). In any case, if my ssh is disconnected for any reason, I can still log back in again at any time and reconnect to my screen session (`screen ls` / `screen -r working-on-XYZ`).